# Chrome Fail Error Codes

Tags: google-chrome, error-code

I've been searching for a while now and I can't find the exact list of all fail to load error code/error description of google chrome.
I'm talking about this the highlighted text
[image]

Can someone give me a link?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I did some digging and I must admit, it's not easy to find a full exhaustive list of all (Chromium) networking error codes.

The full list of all Chromium error codes can be found in the file `net_error_list.h`:
https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/net/base/net_error_list.h

**It looks like Google Chrome prepends `ERR_` to all the codes listed in the above list.**

However, error codes in XHR error responses are slightly different. These codes follow the format of the linux system file `errno.h` as defined by POSIX.1-2001, or C99:
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html

Finally, some common NodeJS errors have been listed at the NodeJS API Documentation:
https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors

I'd like to end this answer with a simple comparison example. The error of an `operation timeout` would be named as follows by the listed 'standards':

- `TIMED_OUT` internally in Chromium.
- `ERR_TIMED_OUT` displayed in Google Chrome.
- `ETIMEDOUT` in the XHR error object (`error.code`).

Using your example:

- `CONNECTION_REFUSED` -> internally in Chromium
- `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` -> displayed in Google Chrome
- `ECONNREFUSED` -> in linux (POSIX.1) or network error stacks

Comment: Its a big help that you pointed that out. Thank you. Still I can't accept this as the correct answer

Comment: @GilbertMendoza could you please elaborate as to why this does not answer your question?

Comment: Its really helpfull that you pointout the differences. Well if what you've given is the COMPLETE error codes then i'll accept it. but I think thats not all the error codes

Comment: @GilbertMendoza The `net_error_list.h` is the (only) networking error list Chrome uses. The given list contains all network errors you could possibly encounter. Go ahead and compare it with the `errno.h` linux file, you will see that all the possible network errors are implemented by chromium.

Comment: See this[1] for the common *crash* error codes, which are independent of the network error codes.

[1] https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/browser/ui/views/sad_tab_view.cc?l=56&rcl=d53fe013f1719d437b632b521e67602514c276df

Comment: Here are all the error codes in JSON: https://github.com/ccnokes/chrome-network-errors/blob/master/index.js

Answer (score 11):

By the way for only listing all error codes

USE :

```
chrome://network-errors/
```

It's about **220** in total as of now in chrome version (***69.0.3497.100***)

Comment: This is a great tip, because each of those errors is hyperlinked and will give you a detailed description on the click-through.

Comment: Except I get the same "STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_HASH" when I try and view this page on the affected PC

Answer (score -1):

I have chromium Version 97.0.4692.71 (Official Build), snap (32 bit), on Description: Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS. The problem was solved using the command in the terminal

***chromium --no-sandbox***

after that everything worked.

Comment: Does this really answer the original question?