# How to catch Chrome error net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND in XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to create chrome extension which will be able to read local files and use code wrote in them. My simplyfied code is:

```
const readFile = (filePath) => {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    xhr.onerror = (error) => {
      reject(error)
    }
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        resolve(xhr.response)
      }
    }
    xhr.ontimeout = function () {
      reject('timeout')
    }
    xhr.open('GET', filePath)
    xhr.send()
  })
}

async function () {
    const code = await readFile(jsFilePath)
    console.log(code)
}
```

This code successfully works when my filePath is correct. But when it is not Chrome console throws this error:

```
GET file:///home/maxim/Documents/test.jsa net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

Usual try/catch block doesn't work

```
async function () {
  try {
    const code = await readFile(jsFilePath)
    console.log(code)
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}
```

How can I catch this type of errors?

Comment: Use `xhr.onloadend = e => e.type !== 'error' ? resolve(xhr.response) : reject(e)` listener instead of `onerror` and `onreadystatechange `

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help in my situation. e.type returns 'loadend' and chrome throws net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND.

Comment: add another console.log in both try and catch and see which one is actually getting printed

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all `net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` is a browser error (see [Chromium/Chrome error list](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/net/base/net_error_list.h), [Chrome fail error codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42524254/chrome-fail-error-codes), so you cannot catch it with JS code.

Specifically `net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` "does not indicate a fatal error.  Typically this error will be generated as a notification".

So the best approach is to attach `onloadend` handler to `XMLHttpRequest`, triggered on Ajax request complete (either in success or failure).

But **you cannot check the status**, in fact values of `status`, `statusText` and `readyState` properties of `XMLHttpRequest` both in the case of file existing and in the case of file not found are always:

```
status: 0
statusText: ""
readyState: 4
```

On the contrary you can check the properties `response`, `responseText` and `responseURL` whose value is "" when the file is not found or in other cases:

```
response: <file content>
responseText: <file content>
responseURL: "file:///..."
```

Other value to check is `event` (ProgressEvent) `loaded` property which has value 0 in case of file not found (or the bytes loaded in other cases).

So the code could be:

```
const readFile = (filePath) => {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
        xhr.onloadend = (event) => {
            console.log("xhr.onloadend", event, xhr.status, xhr.statusText, xhr.readyState, xhr);
            if (event.loaded && xhr.response) {
                resolve(xhr.response);
            } else {
                reject("error");
            }
        }
        xhr.open('GET', filePath);
        xhr.send();
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! 
I think that this is an acceptable solution for my situation)
I found that using `async === false` also may be helpful, because in that case send method throws an error which can be caught in try/catch block. But I think, that Chrome deprecation notice about synchronous request makes your solution better.

Comment: And I found that it is better to use xhr.responseURL instead of xhr.response. In case if our file is empty then xhr.response will be empty too and Promise will reject error.

Comment: Yes, it's true, if the file exists but it's empty xhr.responseURL contains anyway a string (the url/path).