# How to handle Chrome network errors? [net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET, net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED]

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, dom, browser

I am trying to catch the browser errors but I cant find how to do that..Is that possible?

My console is printing:

```
failed to load resource net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

I cannot find a way to catch/intercept this information. I'd tried:

```
<html>
<body>
 ...

 window.onerror = function (msg, url, lineNo, columnNo, error) {...}

</body>
</html>
```

I would like to get as much information as possible from the error, in order to create an error report (stack trace or something like that).

Comment: check out this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48127436/how-to-catch-chrome-error-neterr-file-not-found-in-xmlhttprequest

Comment: @HarryChilinguerian thanks for reply, I saw this one... my problem is that I want to catch the HTML loading errors either, not only a specific ajax call. In this solution, I should create in the XMLHttpRequest object the "onloadend" function. Do you have any idea how to create onloadend to <scripts> tags? Any DOM object... wherever LOL