# Exhaustive list of chromium console errors

Tags: console, chromium

I am looking for an exhaustive list of all errors that can be emitted to the chromium console. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43686321/5578453) SO answer already provided a list of all chromium error codes, but I am looking for all errors that appear in the console. E.g. when a subresource integrity check fails the following error is printed to the console:

```
Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource 'http://127.0.0.1:9616/assets/css/some_css.css' with computed SHA-384 integrity 'Iw54E1Wcqvl8hgVdh49U+WwaGqHp5YstLOVgpoFxv7pT4Lm36Cce7hQ4ZfeXY9wN'. The resource has been blocked.
```

Any help is much appreciated!